# How Can I get a List object by HttpClientResponse?

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I get a List object in "result"? I tried with toList() method on "request" object, but I can't solve this.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {
  var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')); // produces a request object
  var response = await request.close(); // sends the request

  // transforms and prints the response
  var result;

  await for (var contents in response.transform(Utf8Decoder())) {
   result =contents;
  }

  print(result);

}
```

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, response.transform return multiple parts of result, you need to get all by joining them together:

```
  var result = new StringBuffer();
  await for (var contents in response.transform(Utf8Decoder())) {
      result.write(contents);
  }
```

Secondly, you result is just a "text" (in json format), not an "object" as you expect, you need to decode it:

```
  List<dynamic> myList = jsonDecode(result.toString());
  print(myList);
```

Comment: import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {
  var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson'));
  var response = await request.close(); // sends the request

  var result = new StringBuffer();
  await for (var contents in response.transform(Utf8Decoder())) {
      result.write(contents);
  }

  List<dynamic> myList = jsonDecode(result.toString());
  
  print(myList[0]['title']);
}

Comment: 'code'

  var myList = jsonDecode(result.toString());

  List quakes = myList['features'];
  
} 'code'

Answer (score -2):

Simply the following

```
List elements = json.decode(response.body);
```

Comment: error: The getter 'body' isn't defined for the class 'HttpClientResponse'. (undefined_getter at [flutter_app] lib\main.dart:40)